# python file operation-raw input and printing from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, operation

Please have a look at code below : I am trying to get raw input from user and open a file and write it and read from file and print. While reading and printing the file content, I am getting some ASCII values or random values, may be the \n or enter that I do after entering the contents in file is causing the issue. not sure, please help here.
Thanks,
Nithin MP

### Program

```
import os
import codecs
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
try:

  txt = open(filename)
  print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
  print "content:\n",txt.read() 
  a=raw_input("For erasing file enter E or press A to append or press enter to exit :")
  if a=="E":
      txt = open(filename,"r+")
      txt.truncate()
      print "file content erased"
      exit(1)
  elif a=="A":
      b=raw_input("enter text here :")
      #txt = codecs.open(filename,"a+","utf-8")
      txt = open(filename,"a+")
      txt.write(b)
      #print "new file content is :",txt.encode("utf-8")
      print "new file content is :",txt.read()
      exit(0)
  else :
      print "file not modified"
      exit(0)

except Exception as e :
  print e
  #exit(0)
```

Comment: Try to add `txt.flush()` after writing, and also `txt.seek(0)`

Comment: Hi @Bharath Shetty for the edit

Comment: Hi @Michael O for help, I have modified my code with your suggestion and it is working fine. thanks a lot